# JavaScript - dynamic variables won't update - What's the issue?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute, dynamic-variables

**Background**
Hey everyone, first off thanks for your help. This issue has been bothering my for quite a while now and I just can't seem to figure it out.

Some background, I am creating a page that links to a db that has movie posters stored. This page will allow me to retrieve specific movie posters based on two factors: the movieid that is passed and the poster size.

**Specifics**

I am trying to change the value of data-pp-pubid to the input from Publisher ID (in this case King Kong). I am also wanting to do the same thing for data-pp-placementtype to fill from my dropdown box.

This works if I use static information in the html. However, I am wanting to create dynamic variables to save me the trouble of constantly editing the html file. This is what I've got so far.

```
<div>
 <form>
    <select id="generic_size" name="Poster Size">
            <option value="120x90">120x90</option>
            <option value="120x240">120x240</option>
            <option value="120x600">120x600</option>
            <option value="150x100">150x100</option>
            <option value="170x100">170x100</option>
            <option value="190x100">190x100</option>
            <option value="234x400">234x400</option>
            <option value="234x60">234x60</option>
            <option value="250x250">250x250</option>
            <option value="280x280">280x280</option>
            <option value="300x50">300x50</option>
            <option value="300x250">300x250</option>
            <option value="468x60">468x60</option>
            <option value="540x200">540x200</option>
            <option value="720x90">720x90</option>
            <option value="800x60">800x60</option>
    </select>

Publisher ID: <input type="text" value="King Kong" id="movieId">
 <input type="submit" value="Get poster" 
  onclick="javascript:getMovInfo(); setSize(); getPoster();";>
</form>
</div>

        <script type="text/javascript" data-pp-pubid="Mad Max" data-pp-placementtype="120x240"> (function getPoster(d, t) {
        "use strict";
        var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], n = d.createElement(t);
        n.src = "//movietime.adtag.now.com/merchant.js";
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(n, s);
        }(document, "script"));
        </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 function getMovInfo() {
  var movRetrieve= document.getElementById("movieId").value;
  var movInfo = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[2];
  var movSet = movInfo.setAttribute("data-pp-pubid", movRetrieve);
  }

 function setSize (){
  var sizeDropDown= document.getElementById("generic_size");
  var sizeSelected= sizeDropDown.options[sizeDropDown.selectedIndex].value;
  var sizeInScript = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[2];
  var newSize = sizeInScript.setAttribute("data-pp-placementtype", sizeSelected);
 }
</script>
```

Thanks again, this is my first post!

Comment: Why doesn't this work??

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Ive set up this plunker and it seems to work. http://plnkr.co/edit/DsP7Kj31NIayAY5JQptF?p=preview

Comment: The variables get changed, but i need the page to reload with the new variables and location.reload(); does not seem to do the trick

Comment: First: why do you "d", "t" parameters in the function "getPoster" and never use them? Next: in one place you directly use the globally available "document" object and in the function you getPoster expect the document to be passed as parameter.

Comment: Any ideas about the possible issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then you should convert the html data you have to some data in the code. An array ["300x50", ...] will do the job. Then you have to populate your select with the data.

Comment: I don't understand? The data is being populated. The page is just not being reloaded with the dynamic variables